# Extending an Injective Ring Homorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, field-theory

> Let $R$ be a domain and let $\varphi : R \to k$ be an injective ring homomorphism, where $k$ is a field. Prove that there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\phi : Frac(R) \to k$ extending $\varphi$; i.e., $\phi |_{R} = \varphi$.

Proof:

Let $\phi : Frac(R) \to k$ be defined by $\phi ([x,y]) = \varphi(x) \varphi(y)^{-1}$. Since $y \neq 0$ and $\varphi$ is injective (i.e., trivial kernel), we needn't worry about inverting the zero element. Let us now show that it is well-defined. Suppose that $[a,b] = [c,d]$, where $b,d \neq 0$. Then $ad=bc$, and therefore $\varphi(ad) = \varphi (bc)$ or $\varphi (a) \varphi(b)^{-1} = \varphi(c) \varphi (d)^{-1}$ or $\phi ([a,b]) = \phi ([c,d])$, which proves that $\phi$ is well-defined. Let $r \in R$ be arbitrary. Then $\phi ([r,1]) = \varphi(r) \varphi(1)^{-1} = \varphi(r)$, which shows that $\phi$ restricted to $R$ agrees with $\varphi$.

Now we show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. Here is additivity:

\begin{align}
\phi ([a,b] + [c,d]) &= \phi ([ad+bc,bd]) \\ 
&= \varphi(ad+bc) \varphi(bd)^{-1} \\
&= \varphi(a) \varphi(b)^{-1} + \varphi (c) \varphi (d)^{-1} \\
&= \phi([a,b]) + \phi([c,d]) \\
\end{align}

And here is multiplicativity:

\begin{align}
\phi([a,b] \cdot [c,d]) &= \phi([ac,bd]) \\
&= \varphi(ac) \varphi(bd)^{-1} \\ 
&= \varphi(a) \varphi (b)^{-1} \varphi (c) \varphi (d)^{-1} \\
&= \phi ([a,b]) \phi ([c,d])$
\end{align}

Of course, since we are working within a domain, the product $bd$ will not be zero as neither of the terms in the product is zero.

Now we prove uniqueness. Suppose that $f : Frac(R) \to k$ is a ring homomorphism having the same property that $\phi$ has. Then $f([1,y]) = f([y,1]^{-1}) = f([y,1])^{-1} = \varphi(y)^{-1}$, and therefore $f([x,y]) = f([x,1] \cdot [1,y]) = f([x,1]) f([1,y]) = \varphi(x) \varphi (y)^{-1}$, whereby we conclude $f = \phi$.

How does my proof sound?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Very detailed write up. Nice. This is also known as *universal property of  field of fractions*. This shows, field of fractions of an integral domain is *unique up to unique isomorphism*.

Comment: If you don't have any reason to believe there is some problem with your proof, you really ought to post it as a self-answered question. The goal is to avoid the awkward situation that happens so often, where answers are forced to be of the form "Everything's fine." If there is anything wrong with your solution in that form, someone will probably spot it, at least, as easily as they can when the answer is in the question post.