# Prove that if $\Bbb{Q} ≤ E$ and $\Bbb{Q} ≤ F$, then $φ(r) = r$ for all $r ∈\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, ring-homomorphism

Suppose  $E$ and $F$ are fields, and $φ : F → E$ is a ring homomorphism such that
$φ(1) = 1$. I've shown that $φ$ is injective. But if I have $\Bbb{Q} \subset E$ and $\Bbb{Q} \subset F$, how do I show that for every $r \in \Bbb{Q}$, $φ(r) = r$?

Any hints would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Is $Q$ the field of rationals?

Comment: You must mean $\mathbb Q$, the rational numbers, by $Q$, otherwise the claim is false in general (otherwise for $Q=F=E$ you are claiming every field has only the identity as automorphism). So to show that, you will have to use some properties of $\mathbb Q$. As usual, start with $\mathbb Z$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to observe is that $\varphi(\frac{p}{q})=\varphi(pq^{-1})=\varphi(p)(\varphi(q))^{-1}=\frac{p}{q}$ and hence conclude.
This is enough. But for a bit more rigorous argument see below.

First observe that since a field is a simple ring, any homomorphism $\varphi$ is either trivial or injective , i.e $\ker(f)=\{0\}$ or $F$.

So $\varphi(1)=1\implies \varphi$ is injective.

So since both the fields contain $\Bbb{Q}$ they are of characteristic $0$.

Now both $E$ and $F$ contain $\Bbb{Z}$.

Consider $\varphi\vert_{\Bbb{Z}}:\Bbb{Z}\to E$ . That is the restriction of $\varphi$ to $\Bbb{Z}\subset F$

So $\varphi(n)\vert_{\Bbb{Z}}=n\cdot 1=n\in E$

Thus $\varphi\vert_{\Bbb{Z}}$ is an injective ring homomorphism.

Now as $\Bbb{Q}$ is the field of fractions of of $\Bbb{Z}$ . $\varphi\vert_{\Bbb{Z}}$ can be extended uniquely to a homomorphism from the fraction field of $\Bbb{Z}$ i.e of $\Bbb{Q}$. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2437632/extending-an-injective-ring-homorphism)

i.e.

$\bar{\varphi}:\Bbb{Q}\to E$ such that $\bar{\varphi}(\frac{p}{q})=\frac{\varphi(p)}{\varphi(q)}=\frac{p}{q}$

This is again an injective ring homomorphism and hence a bijection from $\mathbb{Q}(\subset F)\to \mathbb{Q}(\subset E)$ and it is precisely the identity map when restricted to $\Bbb{Q}$.

Now by uniqueness you have $\varphi\vert_{\Bbb{Q}}=\bar\varphi$

Comment: Just a short additional comment. A very elegant way of seeing this uses the following argument: Let $k$ denote the intersection of all fields contained in $E$ as $E$ is of characteristic 0 we now that $\mathbb{Z}$ embeds into $E$ and by universal property so does $\mathbb{Q}$. But verbatim the same argument works for every intermediate field of $E$ so $k$ is the rationals. Now the fixed field of $\phi$ is a field and by the above argument contains the rationals.